# Solve an error in ajax pagination

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to add ajax pagination working with codeigniter. Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  applyPagination();

  function applyPagination() {
    $("#ajax_pagingsearc a").on("click", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "ajax=1",
        url: url,
       success: function(msg,status) {

          $("#ajaxdata").html(msg);
          alert(status);
          applyPagination();
        }
      });
    return false;
    });
  }
});
```

It's not working- can anyone please help me?
getting  [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in console

Comment: It means something wrong with your controller or model, post your code

Comment: try to send data as   data : {id : value}

Comment: might be problem on your model or controller. enable debug mode and see response in response tab in console

Answer (score 0):

I think applyPagination function will not work if you call onclick event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

    $("a").on("click", function() {

      var url = $(this).attr("href");

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "ajax=1",
        url: url,
       success: function(msg,status) {

          $("#ajaxdata").html(msg);
          alert(status);
        }
      });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>

<body>

<a href = "process.php">hello</a>
<div id="ajaxdata">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

simple php file `process.php`

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
exit;
?>
```

Follow the below links

[simple pagination](http://code.runnable.com/U8dzQWEzMxxqeQ_E/php-pagination-example-using-mysql-database-for-dbms)

[ajax pagination](http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-jquery-ajax-php/)

I hope you search well before you ask question there are chances you may lose reputation(which is very difficult earn but very easy to lose)